# How can one use Python Selenium to click a link conditionally from a table using criteria from multiple columns?

Tags: python, selenium

I have an html table (example below) where the entries in the first column contain links, and the links all have the same text.  The second column of each row will either be blank or have text.  Another column will have an integer denoting a pack quantity.  Other columns are irrelevant.  Here is the table html:

```
 <table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="gridheader">
      <th width="100">Item</th> 
      <th width="100">Type</th> 
      <th width="100">ID</th> 
      <th width="30">Pack</th> 
      <th width="30">Units</th>
     </tr>
      <tr class="gridbody">
        <td nowrap="">
        <a href='link_url1'>Item 1</a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="">5</td>
        <td nowrap="">No</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="gridbody">
        <td nowrap="">
        <a href='link_url2'>Item 1</a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap="">ABC</td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="">5</td>
        <td nowrap="">No</td>
     </tr>
     <tr class="gridbody">
        <td nowrap="">
        <a href='link_url3'>Item 1</a>
        </td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap=""></td>
        <td nowrap="">2</td>
        <td nowrap="">No</td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Depending upon the job, I may want to click any one of these links. For example, how do I click the link where the Type is **blank** and the Pack is equal to 2?  What about where the Type is ABC and the Pack is 5?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851932/rails-capybara-how-to-click-a-link-in-a-table-row-that-also-contains-unique-tex) is close but not exactly what I need.  Thanks for your help!

Best Regards,

Derrel

Answer (score 0):

Just like any programming task, you should break this into smaller steps. There is nothing in Selenium that will just do this for you. So start by describing the steps in English:

1. Get all rows in the table
2. For each row, if it meets the criteria, then click on the link.

   Let's break step 2 into more detail:

   1. Get all cells in the current row
   2. If the Type cell is blank and the Pack cell is 2, then click on the link in the Item cell.

Repeat this process by describing each step in more detail until you can translate it directly into python code using selenium.

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being my solution.

```
  # Get the table rows
  trs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'gridbody')

  # Loop through the table rows
  for tr in trs:
    # Store the column values from the current row
    tds = tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')

    # Check the conditions - itype has the Type and pack has the Pack Qty
    if tds[1].text == itype and int(tds[3].text.strip()) == pack:
      # Click the link
      tr.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, item).click()

      # Exit the for loop so that the next iteration doesn't occur on a page
      # where this table doesn't exist 
      break
```

I didn't see such an answer while I was searching, so I hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

you can use xpath's predicate to decorate the table row which includes you wanted table cell.

```
type=''
pack='2'
xpath = '//tbody/tr[td[2][.="{type}"] and td[4][.="{pack}"]]/td[1]/a'
        .format(type=type, pack=pack)

println xpath
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()

tr[place predicate at here to decorate the tr tag]
predicate: [td[2][.='']]  // find the row which 2th cell's text is empty
predicate: [td[4][.='2']] // find the row which 4th cell's text is '2'
                      and // need to satisfy the two predicate. 
tr[...]/td[1]/a  // find the link inside the 1st cell of row
```